# Undefined relation on laravel 5

Tags: php, database, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have tow tables:

**users(id,nom,role_id(fk),...)
roles(id,role)**

in users modele i create:

```
    public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','role_id');
}
public function hasRole($role)
{
    $role = $this->role();
    if (!is_null($role)) {
        $role = $role->role;
    } 
    return ($user_role===$role) ? true : false ;
}
public function whatRole()
{
    $user_role = $this->roles();
    if (!is_null($user_role)) {
        $user_role = $user_role->role;
        return $user_role;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in role modal i create :

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

but when i try to use it like this : `Auth::user()->hasRole('medecin')`
i get this error:

```
ErrorException in User.php line 25: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$role (View: C:\wamp\www\Medecin2016\resources\views\pages\role_form.blade.php)

in User.php line 25
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 43
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\Medecin2016\storage\framework\views/018276e247e24f69812c603a17c57319', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 57
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\Medecin2016\resources\views/pages/role_form.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 142
at View->getContents() in View.php line 111
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 80 
.......................
```

Comment: can you paste the full model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making some confusion with your model... With the hasRole method you want to check if the user has the given role (in your case, 'medicin'). Let's check your code to understand what you're actually doing wrong:

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    // Here you override the given string: this means that you actually
    // lose the 'medicin' value. Additionally, you're calling a method
    // that defines the Eloquent relation. There is NO NEED to do
    // anything like that. Maybe you want to call the $this->role
    // property instead of the method...
    $role = $this->role(); // REMOVE THIS

    // Here you should check if the given string is empty or not
    if ( !is_null($role) ) { // Change is_null with empty is better (IMHO)
        // Again, you're overriding the given string ('medicin')
        //
        // $role = $role->role;
    }

    // You are returning the Boolean value according to the result
    return ($user_role===$role) ? true : false ;
}
```

Now, let's try to do something better: changing your method as following should do the trick:

```
public function hasRole($role = '')
{
    if ( !empty($this->role) && $role === $this->role->{FIELD} ) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Change the {FIELD} with the correct field in the roles table. Hope this will help.